# How To Use Nuget Packages in Cake Build Tool

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package, cakebuild

**build.cake:**

```
var target = Argument("target", "Default");

Task("Default")
  .Does(() => {
     var client = new RestSharp.RestClient("www.test.com");
    Information("Hello World!");
});

RunTarget(target);
```

**packages.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
    <package id="Cake" version="0.21.1" />
    <package id="RestSharp" version="105.2.3" />
</packages>
```

**Error Received:**

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RestSharp' could not be fou
>   nd (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `#addin` preprocessor directive to load assemblies from nuget, it'll fetch the package and reference the assemblies within it.

```
#addin nuget:?package=Cake.Foo
#addin nuget:?package=Cake.Foo&version=1.2.3
#addin nuget:?package=Cake.Foo&prerelease
#addin nuget:https://myget.org/f/Cake/?package=Cake.Foo&prerelease
```

You read more about the preprocessor directives at [cakebuild.net](http://cakebuild.net/docs/fundamentals/preprocessor-directives).

Your example script would look something like this:

```
#addin nuget:?package=RestSharp&version=105.2.3

var target = Argument("target", "Default");

Task("Default")
  .Does(() => {
     var client = new RestSharp.RestClient("http://www.test.com");
    Information("Hello World!");
});

RunTarget(target);
```

Comment: Thank you! Does this mean I don't need the packages.config entry?
And is there a way to use the packages.config entry instead?

Comment: Yes, you can use a packages.config file in the Addins folder, and place and entry in that new file for RestSharp. The packages.config file in the root of the tools folder is only for tools. NOTE: You will need the most recent bootstrapper in order for this to work.

Comment: You'll still need to use #addin  or #r directive for the assembly to be loaded and available within the script though.

Comment: @devlead is there any benefit to having it in the config if it has to be in the file regardless?

Comment: @Chazt3n no, preferred way for addins & tools would be the pre-processor directives